# find: missing argument to -exec with +?

Tags: bash, find

So let's say in a bash script I have the following:

```
# Count the number of wood.dat files
numWoodFiles=($( find ./$1_* -type d -exec find {} -type f -name "wood\.dat" \+  | wc -l  ))
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I want to use the `+` operator so that the command runs faster and concurrently instead of the `;` which will run it sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `find ... -exec ... {} +`, the `{}` *must* be the last thing before the `+` (because `find` adds the pathnames to the end of the command).  The error comes from missing the `;` at the end of the first `find` though.

There's no benefit to first find all subdirectories and then execute another search over these, so your `find` command could be replace by a single `find`:

```
find "./$1_"* -type f -name 'wood.dat'
```

This would look for files called `wood.dat` in all directories matching `"./$1_"*`.

The whole assignment would be

```
numWoodFiles=$( find "./$1_"* -type f -name 'wood.dat' | wc -l )
```

I removed the outer `(...)` as we don't need to create an array for a single integer.